# Can't use normally search when using CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios

I am using `CNContactPickerViewController` to be able to choose multiple countacts. My code is straightforward:

```
   class func showContactsPicker(view: UIViewController, delegate: CNContactPickerDelegate) {
        let picker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        picker.delegate = delegate
        view.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact])
    {
        // Do something with contacts
    }
```

I will get an "All contacts" screen on which I can choose multiple contacts (which is fine).

There is a search field at the top and if I try to find anybody, I can see a contact. However, there is no way to add this person to selected contact.

Am I missing something (some parameter) or is this Search field useless?

P.S. I tried to find some app which uses Contacts with multiple selection (vs just choosing one contact) and I can't.

I feel it's iOS bug. One other mentitioning of this problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/87148#87148

Comment: Seeing if you've had any progress on this issue. We're seeing the same problem. Is the next step to create your own picker?

Comment: @djneely Sorry. Just noticed your message. I decided for now to allow to choose only one contact. Most likely I will switch to a custom Contact picker. There are bunch of open source ones (so don't need to create your own)

Comment: We're thinking of doing the same until we build out our own selector. I also submitted a bug report to Apple (#25149960) which they quickly closed saying it was a duplicate of bug #22820325. Not sure what is so hard about fixing a simple table filter but as of now still not fixed in the latest 9.3 updates.

Comment: @djneely Yeah. I agree, it's a tiny bug to fix. My guess that they just has gazzilion of such small issues. As result, some of them wait for a year(s) to be fixed.

Comment: http://www.openradar.me/25433471

Comment: @HamzaGhazouani Thanks

Comment: It is still reproducible in 10.1 =/

Comment: Still around in 11.2! How could this be?? Makes the control unusable for me.

Comment: HII Victor Ronin. I have the same issue. I want to select the multiple contacts by using search. when I search the contact it displays the name and I click on that contact it doesn't perform any action. did you solve that?please suggest me

Comment: @vijju I haven’t found a solution. Please see comments above - it’s known iOS bug. I found back then a 3rd party UI control which can do pretty much the same thing. ( sorry, I don’t remember what was the name of it. )

Comment: @VictorRonin the 3rd party UI control is Ep Contact Picker?. Ok, Thank You for the response.